# SQL Server Generate a specific set of year values from a column which gives me one single date/year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume the following table

[image: Maintable]

I want to use the data above and convert it into the following result

[image: ResultantSet]

The only way I can think to solve this using a temp table and cursor to incrementally add rows to the result which will be time consuming as the records in the original table are currently in thousands and expected to rise exponential.

Anyone got a better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great opportunity for using a tally or numbers table. That is, a table with a single, indexed integer column containing the sorted sequence of non-negative integers. Here's an example of how one would look:

```
number
--- 
0
1
2
3
...
```

With this table, you can perform a join to apply arithmetic operations using a set based approach. Your query would be structured something like this:

```
select a.id,
a.agreementyear + a.incrementalperiodinyears * t.number as yearinfocus
from agreements a
cross join tally t
where a.agreementperiodinyears >= a.incrementalperiodinyears * t.number
order by a.id,
a.incrementalperiodinyears * t.number
```

Having a permanent tally table in your DB often comes in handy, but if you don't, you can create one in a temporary table.

You may need to add a check to the where clause to account for remainders (using mod or by casting to decimal) if the data contains agreement periods and incremental periods which don't line up perfectly. For example, an incremental period of three years but an agreement period of eight.

Comment: +1 Here I was trying to solve this using a recursive CTE... This approach is sooooo much better. Shame on me for not thinking of using a number table. :)

Comment: If you don't have a permanent numbers table, a recursive CTE is a convenient way to create one for a one off.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Wow, never thought of this, will try and let you know! Thanks

Comment: FYI, although convenient, a recursive CTE does not perform well if you need a lot of numbers. Aaron Bertrand has done some pretty extensive testing on this and documented it in [this article](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2).